Application of Banach-Steinhaus (Uniform Boundness Principle)

Let $E, F$ Banach spaces and $W \subset \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ . If for all $(x,f) \in E \times F' : \sup_{T \in W} |f(Tx)| < \infty$, then $\sup_{T \in W} \lVert T \rVert < \infty $ .

I am trying to solve this excercise from a Functional analysis book. In order to do it, I use a corolary of Hahn-Banach Theorem which, fixed $x \in E$, gives for each $T \in W$ a functional $f_T\in F'$ such that $\lVert f_T \rVert = 1 \, \land \, f_T(Tx) = \lVert Tx \rVert$ . Then:
$$\lVert Tx \rVert = |f_T(Tx)| \leq \sup_{S \in W} |f_T (Sx)| < \infty $$
Taking supremum with respect to $T$ the proof would be finished since that would be the Hypothesis of Banach-Steinhaus Theorem. The problem is that I am not sure if I can do it since $f_T$ depends on $T$, so any possible advice or help would be appreciated :)

You cannot make $f$ depend on $T$ in the hypothesis.
Consider the Banach space $E \times F'$ with $\|(x,f)\|=\max \{\|x\|,\|f\|\}$. Define a family of operators $(\Gamma_T)_{T \in W}$ from $E \times F'$ to the scalar field by $\Gamma_T(x,f)=f(T(x))$. Check that $\|\Gamma_T\|= \|T\|$. An application of UBP now finishes the proof.
